# Rails models associations

Tags: ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, model-associations

i'm new to ruby, ruby on rails and coding in general. In order to practice i started creating an app, but i encountered a few problems.

So first i made a User model (Devise), with an Admin role (boolean). Then i have a **City**, **Neighbourhood** and **Workplace** models. So now i have a hard time associatiating them.
**City (has_many) Neighbourhood (has_many) Workplace**
I am not sure if that's the best approach for the current situation.
Each User has to be able to, be assigned to a different city or neighbourhood.

Then comes the routing problem. I made nested routes:

```
resources :cities do
  resources :neighbourhoods do
    resources :worksites
  end
end
```

But the rails convention is not to have nested routes deeper than 1 level.
They do work, but the address becomes quite long. And that's not something i'd like.

```
cities/city.id/neighbourhoods/neighbourhood.id/worksites/worksite.id
```

How would you suggest me to proceed ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I would call it a 'Rails convention' although I agree 3 levels of nesting might be a bit much depending on your usage. You can flatten it out by adding `shallow:true` to your resource (see this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources which also has several other options you can use to simplify your routes). You could also create a url that looks like `/:city_id/:neighbourhood_id/worksite_id` though that would mean more work and doing some things for yourself since you are going off the rails standard.

Comment: I should also add that something I consider with routes is making sure that URLs don't change. For example if a worksite could move to a different neighborhood then your url would no longer be valid and I would definitely be using a shallow url that wouldn't change. It might also look better to use a 'slug' built from the worksite name or a random hash rather than an id for each part of the url.

Comment: The url will definitely be slugged, and the shallow approach looks like the best solution for the routes. I am just not sure if the app design is good. Apart from the routes, all the associations i need to do seem very confusing. I need more suggestions on the matter, meanwhile i'll just have to experiment.

Comment: In my experience, those associations are pretty much defined by the structure of your data and what you need to be able to do with it. You just need to decide how much you want to expose to your users. There are pros and cons either way.